# Can I run multiple pipelines in a single GitLab repo using GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I know that I can't have multiple gitlab-ci.yml files in one repo, but it still seems fairly limited. Say for example I have one set of tests I want to run whenever a change is pushed or on PRs, and another set I want to run every 24 hours. Is there a way to do that, or do I only get one set of tests I have to use whenever I want to run CI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) syntax. You can use this in combination with regex for commit message, [ci_pipeline_source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#common-if-clauses-for-rules) or any other available CI variables.

```
job1:
  script: 
    - do something on schedule only
  rules:
    - if: '"$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE" == "schedule"'
      when: always

job2:
  script: 
    - runs on Merge request pipeline
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: always
    when: never

job2:
  script: 
    - runs on changes to anything in src directory or Dockerfile
  rules:
    - changes:
        - src/*
        - Dockerfile
```

Note you can also [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html) multiple CI templates in your gitlab-ci.yml. Additonally, you can include a CI template with ["hidden"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#hide-jobs) job templates that you can reference with [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends):

```
# Include ci files 
include:
 - local: '/templates/.scheduled-job-template.yml' # CI template with hidden job (.scheduled_job) that runs on schedule
 - local: '/templates/.lint-and-validate.yml' # contains jobs for linting and validating project

job1:
  extends:
    - .scheduled_job
  rules:
    - if: '"$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE" == "schedule"'
      when: always

job2:
  script: 
    - runs on Merge request pipeline
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: always
    when: never
```

In doing this you can compose the jobs/pipelines you want in its own yml file and then define the jobs using those templates in the gitlab-ci.yml, which will help keep things maintainable and clear if you are running numerous different pipeline/pipeline configurations from the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it via `rules` keyword. It has multiple condition with environment variables or branch name or schedules. If you add detail about you want to do, i try to

[Gitlab CI Rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)